# TypeError: Cannot read property 'collections' of undefined sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, tedious

am using sails-sqlserver as my adapter am just trying the create a new row in the database in one of the follwing models.

This is the first model :

```
// Roles.js

module.exports = {

  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    approval_level: {
      model: 'approval_levels'
    },

    specified: {
      type: 'boolean' 
    },                
    entity_operations: {
      collection: 'entity_operations',
      via: 'roles',
      dominant: true
    },

    users: {
      collection: 'system_users',
      via: 'role'
    }

  },

  createRole: function (name, approval_level, cb) {

    values = {
      name: name,
      approval_level: approval_level
    };

    Roles.create(values).exec(cb);
  },


  getAll: function (cb) {
    Roles.find().exec(cb);
  }


};
```

This is the second model :

```
// Entity_Operations.js

module.exports = {

    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,

    attributes: {

        entity_name: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        operation: {
            model: 'operations'
        },

        roles: {
            collection: 'roles',
            via: 'entity_operations'
        }

    },

    getAll: function (cb) {
        Entity_operations.find().exec(cb);
    }

};
```

These two models have a many to many relationship together what am trying to do is just this :

```
Entity_operations.create({
            entity_name: 'example',
            operation: 6
        }).exec((err, entity: Entity_operations) => {
            console.log(entity);
        });
```

then this error comes out without explaining anything that could help me know from where this error is coming from :

```
 /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/sails-sqlserver/lib/adapter.js:435
      Object.keys(connections[connection].collections[collection].definition).forEach(function(key) {
                                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collections' of undefined
    at Object.getPrimaryKey (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/sails-sqlserver/lib/adapter.js:435:42)
    at Object.create (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/sails-sqlserver/lib/adapter.js:374:24)
    at module.exports.create (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/dql.js:84:13)
    at child.createValues (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:220:16)
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:74:20
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:269:32
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:269:32
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at child.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/schema.js:152:44)
    at fn (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/callbacksRunner.js:41:10)
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:181:20
    at iterate (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at Object.async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
    at Object.async.forEachSeries.async.eachSeries (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:214:22)
    at Object.runner.beforeCreate (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/callbacksRunner.js:44:9)
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:180:17
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
    at iterate (/opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:29
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
    at /opt/nodejs/back-heaven/dev/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
```

when i tried the same code in a controller it succeded am trying it in a seeder of my own implementation this seeder before it starts i make a sails object programmatically and call sails.load

like this :

```
let myApp = new Sails();

    myApp.load({}, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      // this execute the seeds in the database seeder class
      let seeder = require(`../../api/seeders/${scope.args[0]}`);
      seeder.handle(() => {

        myApp.lower((err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(`Seeder ` + scope.args[0] + ` finished seeding`);
        });

      });

    });
```

I also tried with sails.lift() and still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Found out the problem i was just making a callback function that should call sails.lower() which unload or close the sails I was putting it in the wrong place where it was called even before the model creation code starts.just forget to call it in the database callback function.

so , for anyone else who is facing this same problem in sails your problem is that sails actually not loaded or maybe when the operation you were working on started sails was working but, after that for some reason sails stopped which made the models do this weird looking problem I hope sails handle such errors in their code to show out a more expressive error messages.

I hope this helps anyone.